# the profit factor still NaN for EMA crossover PINE SCRIPT

Tags: pine-script

pine script allows me to upload EMA in graphic without errors, but I have not profit factor and I see long entry/exit long in the same place, same position. Also I have another problem: when I try to put profit (for trailing) I have error. Thanks for your time

```
//@version=4
strategy('ema 18/20', overlay=true)
longCondition = crossover(ema (close, 18), ema(close, 20))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
float takeprofit = 0.3
strategy.exit (id= "exit long (%)", profit=0.01)
buy = crossover(ema (close, 18), ema(close, 20))
sell = takeprofit  == true
fast = ema(close, 18)
slow = ema(close, 20)
plot(fast, color=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plot(slow, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `profit` argument of `strategy.exit()` is specified in ticks. 0.01 is probably way too less.

If you want to have percentage based take profit, you should use `strategy.position_avg_price` and calculate your target price. Then you can pass this take profit price to `limit` your `strategy.exit()` call as `limit`.

```
take_profit_percentage = 0.01 // 1%
long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + take_profit_percentage)
strategy.exit ("Long Exit", limit=long_tp_price)
```